# Inserting new object past row 8 the app crashes on scroll with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have an app that does all things it is supposed to do with the first 8 rows of a UITableView... Once I add that 9th row (so the tableview must scroll) the app crashes...

I have tried numerous variations, but nothing seems to work... I can add cells to my row, as many times as I like, but once I "fill" that 9th row in the table, the app crashes with

**`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`**

Here is some code used to generate the info in the row in tableview (tabledata is a NSMutableArray and areaNumber.text comes from a customCell)

```
-(IBAction)save_area:(id)sender {

{
        UITableView *tableView = self.myTable;
        NSInteger sections = tableView.numberOfSections;
        NSMutableArray *cells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]  init];
        for (int section = 0; section < sections; section++) {
            NSInteger rows =  [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section];
            for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
                SodTableCell *cell = [self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];//**here, for those cells not in current screen, cell is nil**
                [cells addObject:cell];

                [tabledata removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

                NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                NSObject * object_areaNumber = [prefs objectForKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"];

                if(object_areaNumber != nil){
                    [tabledata insertObject:cell.areaNumber.text atIndex:indexPath.row];
                }

                NSUserDefaults *save1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [save1 setObject:self.tabledata forKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"];
                [save1 synchronize];
                NSLog(@"From save button %@",[save1 valueForKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The table can create row after row after row beyond the 9 cells, hundreds if I wanted, and the scroll works... it is when I populate information into the 9th row and which to save that information entered using the code you see above.  Any help, much appreciated...

EDIT

In my tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

SodTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[SodTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

if(indexPath.row >= tabledata.count && [self isEditing]){

    cell.areaNumber.text = @"new";

}else{

    cell.areaNumber.delegate = self;
    cell.areaNumber.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSUserDefaults *save1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [save1 setObject:self.tabledata forKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"];
    [save1 synchronize];
    NSLog(@"From cell configuration %@",[save1 valueForKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"]);
}

return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think you are absolutely, totally misunderstanding how tableview cells are used. cellForRowAtIndexPath is not a function that you should ever call yourself. You implement. UITableView calls it when needed.

Comment: Any information that you would try to store MUST come from your data model. Cells are just for displaying information.

Comment: @designer Can you show me where you create `self.tabledata`?

Comment: Sir, do take a time to read about how tableview (and collectionview or any other reusable view) works here: https://xcodenoobies.blogspot.my/2017/11/how-to-create-reusable-views-with.html?m=1 It also has downloadable sample code. It will help you to understand tableview concept and how to code it properly. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @gnasher729 I will continue to learn about this... You are right... This is the first time I have every tried to implement this type of code in my apps.  While I have a few in the app store, non use this type of code structure...

Comment: @trungduc... I try to show number of rows here `- (NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //if the current view is in editing mode
    //add an extra row
    int addRow = [self isEditing] ? 1 : 0;
    return tabledata.count + addRow;
}`

Comment: @trungduc... I also show in viewDidLoad as `tabledata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    if([tabledata count]==0){
        //Your array is empty so you have to call it with @"yourKey"
        tabledata=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tablerow_area_input_by_user"]]mutableCopy];
        // not sure if I need to add "mutableCopy" to end or not
    }
    
    numberOfSection = 1;
    [myTable reloadData];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I have reviewed all the comments made regarding my misunderstanding of UITableViews and related code...

If you review the following link (to my Vimeo page), you should see some nifty things...

[Working Example on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/242505237)

I was able to load more than the 8 cells in my original problem (as noted in original question) and was even able to **load empty rows that the user can save and fill in later!** Everything is saved in NSUserDefaults and can be saved, edited or deleted...

Again, thank you for your help... of course, comments that actually helped me are always more welcome and constructive, than the one's that merely pointed out that I didn't know what I was doing...

Answer (score 1):

I won't talk about how to use `UITableView` by a right way, i just show you why you got crash.

The error says that you are trying to insert a `nil` object to a array. As i guess, the root of problem is the below line.

```
[tabledata insertObject:cell.areaNumber.text atIndex:indexPath.row];
```

To solve it, check `cell.areaNumber.text` before inserting to array.

```
if(object_areaNumber != nil && cell.areaNumber.text){
    [tabledata insertObject:cell.areaNumber.text atIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```